# How to remember permission for <p:photoCam> on client side?

Tags: flash, jsf-2, primefaces, permissions, webcam

In my application, I use PrimeFaces's `<p:photoCam>` to allow users to take photos using webcam. My problem is that the Flash component keep asking for permissions every time a user clicks `Take a photo`. There's no checkbox for `Remember this setting`.

In another question from Stackoverflow, an answer suggested that `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY)` needs to be called before accessing the camera. I'd be very grateful if you could show me how to do this in JSF :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this needs to be done inside the PrimeFaces-bundled `photocam.swf` file as served by `<p:photoCam>`. You'd need to [create an issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) at PrimeFaces guys and request them for this feature to be added.

In the meanwhile, an alternative when you're actually proficient with Flash, you could also edit the `photocam.swf` file to include that line and then provide it via your webapp on exactly the same resource ID `/resource/primefaces/photocam/photocam.swf`. It'll be automatically preferred over the PrimeFaces-bundled one.